# Where is the Magic SysRq key on the ASUS P50IJ?

Tags: linux, asus-laptop, linux-kernel

The title is the question. Up to now, I was unable to find it. The proposed solutions I could find on Wikipedia, Wikibooks, superuser.com are not working for me. I have not found any information specific for the ASUS P50IJ.

Comment: Does the machine have a PrintScreen key? SysRq is usually located on the same key.

Comment: SysRq exists but it doesn't work as explained in the docs which I have found.

Comment: What OS and distribution are you using? You might need to configure the feature to work properly.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 30. While using "showkey -s", I can observe that pressing "Fn" doesn't produce a scan code, but it changes the produced scan code of some keys when pressed at the same time than these keys.